# Default Activity Not Found & App Not Showing in Launcher

Tags: android, android-launcher

I cleared all the bugs... Recently before running this app it was showing "No default activity found" I changed configuration to "Nothing" & also added Android Manifest.xml file.

After successful build, Emulator shows app in settings>>app management.

But,

There is nothing in Apps Menu. Even I tried manually installing this app in my device. But it says "App Not Installed"

Share your experience. Help me out. Thank you.

Please include all manifest functions into this code, if I am missing something. This app is cloud storage app. 
This is my manifest file :

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

  <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:supportsRtl="true"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  </application>
</manifest>```
````

Comment: Try Bulid > Clean Project and run again

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes android studio has quircks and bugs.

In this case when it complains of activity not found even though you know it's there do the following:

1. clean build - see if it works
2. remove cable of device reattach cable of device - see if it works
3. restart android studio - see if it works
4. invalidate caches and restart - see if it works

if none of the above work, that means you have some place in that activity that in theory compiles, in practice there is a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your activity tag

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```